# Plot Dependencies of Functions in R-Package

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I am developing an R package that also includes C++ functions via Rcpp and would like to visualise the dependencies of the functions, both of R functions and C++ functions. I saw the two very nice approaches [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44143110/visualizing-r-function-dependencies) and like both answers (mvbtools and DependenciesGraph). With DependenciesGraph I can visualize the correct nodes, so also the R and C++ functions are represented as nodes, however the vertices (the dependencies) are not covered. Does anyone know how to do that? Thanks