# Script to Flowchart in R

Tags: r, graphviz, flowchart, diagrammer

I usually write modular scripts with several functions. When things grow, it's difficult to keep track of what function calls which (naming them like `01-first.R` `02-second.R` is not always possible and I'd rather not use that as the definitive solution).

Here's an example of a potential `script.R` that would run 3 "main" functions with a helper.

```
first <- function(...){
  # do data things
  return(first_output)
}

second <- function(first_output){
  # do data things
  # call helper
  x <- helper(...)
  # do things to x
  return(second_output)
}

third <- function(second_output){
  # do data things
  return(result)
}
```

I would love to get something like this

[image]

Which can be generated within R using the `diagrammeR` package.

```
grViz("
digraph boxes_and_circles {

  # a 'graph' statement
  graph [overlap = true, fontsize = 10]

  # several 'node' statements
  node [shape = box,
        fontname = Helvetica]
  first; second; helper; third;

  # several 'edge' statements
  first->second second->helper 
  helper -> second
  second->third 
  third -> result
}
")
```

Just that (what function calls what other one) would be great. What would be truly awesome is a way to display the types of bifurcations depending on the arguments (e.g, say `first` has a `go_to_third=FALSE` by default but if `go_to_third=TRUE` it jumps directly to `third`). Having the classes of objects the functions are dealing with would also be great.

---

I have checked this question [Visualizing R Function Dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44143110/visualizing-r-function-dependencies)
and I wonder whether there are better ways to do this, visually better.

---

This question is similar to this one in MATLAB [Automatically generating a diagram of function calls in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518200/automatically-generating-a-diagram-of-function-calls-in-matlab) and I'm OK with a hack using GraphViz from outside R.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly what you are after but I've been working on a library to visalise dplyr pipelines:

https://github.com/terminological/dtrackr

It can do more or less what you want but at a slightly more granular level. I'd be grateful for any feedback as still experimental.

Comment: Oh wow, this is super useful (not really what I am looking for but great that you have done this!!!)