# Diagram to see dependency ambong object in R

Tags: r

I've been searching some code or package for visualizing object dependencies in R, which would be very useful to undestand big process models with many variables in a simple sight. For example:

```
a <- 5
b <- 3+2*a
c <- 23
d <- b*c
```

It should show something like this: [Diagram result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgjFl.jpg)

So far, I've only found posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44143110/visualizing-r-function-dependencies#_=_) , but it doesn't solve my issue.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have a look here: <https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/CodeDepends/vignettes/intro.html>

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, I have read before, but it is for functions or packages, not for objects.

Answer (score 2):

This is a solution but it requires that you know upstream the link between your letters.

You can use the "graph_from_adjacency_matrix" function from package igraph.
You have to fill the matrix with the number of link between each letter (e.g. 1 stands for 1 arrow from first to second letter ; 0 stands for no link).

```
# 0- Import library
library(igraph)

# 1- Prepare empty matrix to show link between each letter
matNetwork <- matrix(NA, nrow=4, ncol=4)
rownames(matNetwork) <- LETTERS[1:4]
colnames(matNetwork) <- LETTERS[1:4]

# 2- Fill the matrix with link between letters
matNetwork[,"A"] <- c(0,1,0,0)
matNetwork[,"B"] <- c(0,0,0,1)
matNetwork[,"C"] <- c(0,0,0,1)
matNetwork[,"D"] <- c(0,0,0,0)

# 3- Build the graph object
network <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(matNetwork)

# 4- Plot it
plot(network)
```

You can also change the shape of links between letters

Here are some examples:
https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/257-input-formats-for-network-charts.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sadly, if I understand your answer, I need precisely to build that matrix automatically and visualize their dependencies.